Is checking a users authentication status before allowing access to a page considered as Authentication or Authorization?
When a protected route is created by verifying the user authentication status or when an authenticated user is restricted from accessing the login and register page, is this considered as Authentication or Authorization?
For example, in a React application were a protected route is created using the following code:
function ProtectePage() {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = getUser()

    if (!user) {
      router.push("/login")
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <h1>Protected route</h1>`
  )
}

export default ProtectedPage

Is this authentication or authorization?

Authentication! While preventing login for authenticated users might seem like Authorization it s more like a logical extension of Auth they re already verified, so no need to log in again

Okay. What about the protected routes. Is it when I start restricting access based on the user's role that it is considered authorization?

yep! exactly ! restricting access to certain routes or resources based on a user's role or permissions is the authorization mecanism.
